# Get Build Agent ID using Build Agent Name

Tags: powershell, devops

I am automating the process of turning build agents, using the Powershell script, which would run on a set time daily, before triggering the regression. I am not able to get the build agent ID using build agent name, where Build Agent Name would be user provided & settable at queue time.

Tried searching for everything around this, however did not found anything helpful(in my context) yet. I tried some code around this part. The main concern is I am able to get the count, but now the value. Check the output, which I am getting Following is the code I tried.

```
// Getting the list of Agent ID's from the Environmental Variables, splitting & saving in an array.
$agentID = $env:agentIDs -split ","
$URI = "https://URL.com/_apis/distributedtask/pools/xx/agents"
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Content-Type","application/json")
$headers.Add("Authorization","Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN")
foreach ($element in $agentID)
{
  $poolresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Method GET -Headers $Headers
  echo $poolresponse
  // Count is giving the count correct.
  echo "count : $($poolresponse.count)"
  // However struggling with getting the value.
  echo "value : $($poolresponse.value)"
}
```

Actual Output:

```
count value                                                                                                            

----- -----                                                                                                            

   10 {@{systemCapabilities=; _links=; maxParallelism=1; createdOn=; authorization=; id=133;...}]}
count : 10
value :
```

**Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: While you are iterating `$agentID` with the foreach - without ***using*** $element in the Invoke-RestMethod it would return the same response each time. To expand `value` use the `. property dereference operator` => `$poolresponse.value`

Answer (score 0):

Since it was returning an array in the value, thus not displaying.
I have used it as: **$poolresponse.value[$i]** in a for loop where it worked absolutely fine.

Though Thanks for the help @LotPings.